# Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint.
What should i do first to enable truncate?

details:

```
(
    `guacamole`.`guacamole_connection_history`, 
    CONSTRAINT `guacamole_connection_history_ibfk_2` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`connection_id`) 
    REFERENCES `guacamole`.`guacamole_connection` (`connection_id`)
)
```

I want to clear guacamole_connection table for development testing.

[image: DB structure]

Comment: Delete from guacamole_connection_history before you delete from guacamole_connection.

Comment: Do i must trancate all connected tables?

Comment: Yes, you do. And deep level first, then go up on the hierachly

Comment: Why don't you drop the whole test database and re-create it? You need routines (scripts) for that anyway.

Comment: Just drop the Foreign Key, truncate the table then recreate the Foreign Key

Comment: @jarlh Good point I have dump file. I only need to remove INSERTS from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add a constraint adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`? Then all you need to do is `TRUNCATE guacamole_connection CASCADE`

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    guacamole_connection_history 
ADD CONSTRAINT 
    guacamole_connection_history_cascade_delete 
    FOREIGN KEY (connection_id) 
    REFERENCES guacamole_connection (connection_id) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then just run `TRUNCATE guacamole_connection CASCADE`

Comment: TRUNCATE guacamole_connection CASCADE;      returns: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASCADE' at line 1    All tables was created with ON DELETE CASCADE but without ON UPDATE CASCADE. Is it enough?

Comment: yes you don't need the update, I just added `UPDATE` to show that you can do both. Try it without the update.

Answer (score 23):

You can do truncate by skipping foreign key checks.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
TRUNCATE table1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

TRUNCATE it's not equivalent to DELETE: TRUNCATE it's DDL operations while DELETE is a DML operation. In other words TRUNCATE alter the table structure (i.e. freeing storage and modifying other properties depending on RDBMS you are working on) while DELETE just modify the data on in performing every validation that your model has specified (i.e. foreing key constraints, check constraints, etc.)

Why would you want to truncate the table? Well, it's faster as it doesn't has to run any validation (that's why your FK are affecting the truncate operation), and allows you to free all the space the table (and it's index) is currently allocating.

So, if you want to truncate your table you should:

1. DISABLE related FK
2. TRUNCATE all related tables.
3. ENABLE the previously disabled FKs

Internally the operation use to be (again depending on the RDBMS) equivalent to DROP and CREATE the FKs. The difference usually is related to the permissions needed as conceptually it's not the same to create/delete a FK than enable/disable it

Answer (score -2):

Be sure to remove entries from any dependent tables first. For example:

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE guacamole_connection_history;
 TRUNCATE TABLE guacamole_connection;
```

Comment: I've done that but still get the same error. Maybe picture would be helpfull.

Comment: It seems like a bug in MySQL, even after truncating the dependent (child) tables, you can't truncate main (parent) table.